# Who is the Vaishya Rishi Sankila?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, caste-system, brahmins, ancestry

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10031/36), every Brahmana is a descendant of sages, which is why every Gotra or clan of Brahmins has an associated list of Pravaras, a list of the sages they're descended from. For instance, I am a Brahmin belonging to Vadhula Gotra, and my Pravaras are "Bhargava, Vaitahavya, Savedasa", which means that I am descended from the sage Savedasa, who is a descendant of the sage Vitahavya (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7122/36)), who is a descendant of the sage Bhrigu.  But Brahmanas are not the only ones with Gotra Pravaras; [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=QZhtAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA197&dq=%22I%20SHALL%20now%20tell%20how%20those%20Brahmans%20who%20are%20ignorant%20of%20their%20own%20gotra%20and%20pravara%20are%20to%20take%20the%20pravara%20and%20marriage%20restrictions%20of%20their%20own%20teacher%20(since%20they%20stand%20as%20sons%20to%20their%20teacher).%20As%20there%20is%20doubt%20on%20this%20point%2C%20the%20all-wise%20Apastamba%20and%20the%20rest%20resolve%20the%20doubt%20by%20saying%3A%22&pg=PA195#v=onepage&q&f=false) is what the Baudhayana Shrauta Sutras say about the Pravaras for Kshatriyas and Vaishyas:

> Kshatriyas have a three-rishi (pravara) "Manava, Aida, Paururavasa" for the Hotri, "like Pururavas, Ida, Manu", for the Adhvaryu.  **Vaishyas have a three-rishi (pravara) "Bhalandana, Vatsapra, Mankila" for the Hotri, "like Mankila, Vatsapri, Bhalandana" for the Adhvaryus.**

Now the Pravaras for Kshatriyas make some measure of sense; you have Vaivasvata Manu, then Vaivasvata Manu's son/daughter Ila, and then Ila's son Pururavas who is the ancestor of lunar dynasty kings.  (Although there is still the issue of how these Pravaras would apply to solar dynasty kings.). But I'm interested in the Pravaras for Vaishyas.

I think Bhalandana and Vatsapri refer to the figures mentioned in [this chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/2/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam, who were descendants of Vaivasvata Manu's son Dishta:

> Diṣṭa had a son by the name Nābhāga. **This Nābhāga, who was different from the Nābhāga described later, became a vaiśya by occupational duty. The son of Nābhāga was known as Bhalandana, the son of Bhalandana was Vatsaprīti**, and his son was Prāṁśu. Prāṁśu’s son was Pramati, Pramati’s son was Khanitra, Khanitra’s son was Cākṣuṣa, and his son was Viviṁśati.

But my question is, who is the third figure Mankila mentioned in the Gotra  Pravaras for Vaishyas?

If it helps, the name Mankila is sometimes spelled as Manktila.  Does anyone know any scriptures that mention a Vaishya named Mankila or Manktila?

EDIT: It looks like this Vaishya Rishi may be named Sankila, not Mankila; here's what [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/iWt3) from the Matsya Purana says:

> Bhalandaka, Vashashva, **Sankila** are the chiefs of the Vaishya clan and are the great Mantrakrits.

And [this excerpt](https://ia801406.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/22/items/BrahmandaPurana/BrahmandaPuI_jp2.zip&file=BrahmandaPuI_jp2/BrahmandaPuI_0401.jp2&scale=2&rotate=0) from the Anusanga Pada of the Brahmanda Purana says the same thing:

> Bhalandana, Vatsa and **Samkila** - these three are composers of Mantras and are remembered as the most excellent ones among Vaishyas.

Also, using the Rig Veda Anukramani in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36), I found out that three hymns of the Rig Veda were heard by Vatsapri son of Bhalandana: [Book 9 Hymn 68](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv09068.htm), [Book 10 Hymn 45](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10045.htm), and [Book 10 Hymn 46](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10046.htm).  I haven't found any hymns heard by Bhalandana or Mankila/Sankila though. Finally, I found the stories of Nabhaga, Bhalandana, and Vatsapri in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/RlTm) from the Markandeya Purana.

Answer (score 5):

I hav been looking for this Mankila too but the only place I found his name mentioned is in a Hindi book written on the origin of my clan - Agarwals. The book is titled **'Agrasen Agroha Agrawal'** and was written in 1977.

> [image]

It connects the Agarwals to Dishta the son of Vaivasvat Manu and states that **Mankila was another son of Vatsapri besides Pramshu**:

> [image]

Unfortunatly there is no english translation avaialable so had to share the original Devnagari image. The genealogy goes further to reach **Maharaj Agrasen** who is considered the forefather of all Agarwals/Marwaris but I am not sharing those details sinc ethey are not relevant here. Coming back to **Mankila** it is noteworthy that the **[Markandeya Puran](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/MarkandeyaPurana.html)** also mentions that Vatsapri had more than one son:

> **Sunanda gave birth to 12 sons. Their names were Pranshu, Praveer, Shoor, Suchakra, Vikram, Krama, Bala, Balaak, Chand, Prachand, Suvikram and Swarup. After growing up, Pranshu became the king.**

Presumably, one of these was also known as Mankila or Sankila but which one it was it is hard to say from this much evidence. Shall update the answer in case I find more stuff on him.

Comment: Interesting.  So it says Agrasen was a descendant of Mankila?  Also, are Aggarwals Vaishyas?

Comment: Yup. All Marwaris, Agarwals and even some Jains come under this category.